# How can I make DataTable columns at least as wide as the header text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I notice that when using [DataTables](http://datatables.net), column headers are sometimes word wrapped, since the width is apparently just calculated based on content in the table body. How can I configure DataTables to make columns at least wide enough to hold header text without wrapping?

Comment: have you tried white-space: nowrap; using css?

Comment: @Ziga That did the trick, although I would still prefer configuring DataTables directly. You may want to submit this as an answer, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried `white-space: nowrap;` using css?

Comment: I have tried white-space in td or th css... but no affect ... :(